# Missing the spaces with KableOne (package "TableOne)

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I make an .rmd for report of my scientific analysis.

I use habitually the "TableOne" package, with success. Creating my Tableone results as follow :

```
(CreateTableOne(data = analysis_swan_df,
                    vars = varlist, factorVars = factorvarlist))
```

which renders that in the console :

```
                          Overall       
  n                          2424        
  Age (mean (SD))           51.97 (2.68) 
  RACE (%)                               
     Black                    720 (29.7) 
     Chinese                  207 ( 8.5) 
     Japanese                 261 (10.8) 
     Caucasian               1197 (49.4) 
     Hispanic                  39 ( 1.6) 
  BMI (mean (SD))           28.89 (7.35) 
  Glucose (mean (SD))       94.26 (31.12)
  Smoker = Yes (%)            320 (13.9) 
  LDL (mean (SD))          121.11 (33.54)
  HDL (mean (SD))           58.20 (14.91)
  CRP (mean (SD))            4.07 (6.79) 
  bp_category (%)                        
     Normal                  1105 (51.8) 
     Elevated                 269 (12.6) 
     Hypertension Stage 1     456 (21.4) 
     Hypertension Stage 2+    302 (14.2) 
  Exercise = Yes (%)         1520 (70.9) 
  Chol_Ratio (mean (SD))     3.21 (0.86)
```

I usually copy/paste or export in a .csv with write.csv.

Today, i want to import this table in a .pdf with rmarkdow.

The package provide a function "kableone" :

```
kableone(CreateTableOne(data = analysis_swan_df,
                        vars = varlist, factorVars = factorvarlist))
```

Which renders taht :

```
    Overall
n   2424
Age (mean (SD)) 51.97 (2.68)
RACE (%)     
Black   720 (29.7)
Chinese 207 ( 8.5)
Japanese    261 (10.8)
Caucasian   1197 (49.4)
Hispanic    39 ( 1.6)
BMI (mean (SD)) 28.89 (7.35)
Glucose (mean (SD)) 94.26 (31.12)
Smoker = Yes (%)    320 (13.9)
LDL (mean (SD)) 121.11 (33.54)
HDL (mean (SD)) 58.20 (14.91)
CRP (mean (SD)) 4.07 (6.79)
bp_category (%)  
Normal  1105 (51.8)
Elevated    269 (12.6)
Hypertension Stage 1    456 (21.4)
Hypertension Stage 2+   302 (14.2)
Exercise = Yes (%)  1520 (70.9)
Chol_Ratio (mean (SD))  3.21 (0.86)
```

My problem is that the spaces which indent the categorical data are not reported. This is detrimental to the readability of the results.

I try that :

```
tab1 <- CreateTableOne(data = analysis_swan_df,
                            vars = varlist, factorVars = factorvarlist) 
   
tab1exp <- print(tab1, catDigits = 1, contDigits=2, quote = FALSE, noSpaces = TRUE)

kable(tab1exp)
```

...with the same result.

I coerce that in a data.table without success :

```
tab1 <- CreateTableOne(data = analysis_swan_df,
                            vars = varlist, factorVars = factorvarlist) 
   
tab1exp <- print(tab1, catDigits = 1, contDigits=2, quote = FALSE, noSpaces = TRUE) %>% as.data.table()

kable(tab1exp)
```

and in a data.frame with little success :

```
tab1 <- CreateTableOne(data = analysis_swan_df,
                            vars = varlist, factorVars = factorvarlist) 
   
tab1exp <- print(tab1, catDigits = 1, contDigits=2, quote = FALSE, noSpaces = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame()

kable(tab1exp)
```

Instead of spaces, I get this "X...", which is not really satisfying.

It seems that print a tableone object returns silently a matrix that is used by kable, but the spaces are are missing, contrary to what is displayed in the console. I don't understand how to preserve them. How can this be arranged?